# What is the probability of obtaining a sum of $10$ in two consecutive throws of two dice in the first $8$ throws?

Tags: probability

We are playing with two dice until we get $10$ as the sum of the results two times in a row.

(i) What is the probability of having gotten this in $8$ throws?

(ii) What's the probability of having thrown a sum less than $10$ exactly $8$ times before we stopped?

My attempt:

i) The elements of ordered pairs that add up to $10$ are $(4,6), (6,4)$ and $(5,5)$ that appear on the $7$th and $8$th throw and therefore its probability is $3/36$. I don't know how much I correctly tackled the problem.

The second one a little bit confusing. Any help please.

Comment: Is the second question supposed to read what is the probability of having thrown a sum less than $10$ exactly $8$ times before we stopped?

Comment: Yes, @N.F.Taussig.

Answer (score 1):

(i) What is the probability of having gotten this in 8 throws?

Solution: You didn't consider the all possible events.
In order to calculate the required probability, you have to consider the throws before $7th$ for not getting the sum of $10$ in consecutive throws.

since you've got the sum in $7th$ & $8th$ throw, therefore in the $6th$ throw you have a constraint of not getting a sum $10$ but all from $1$ to $5$ have a possibility of getting a sum of $10$ (not consecutively).

let $p$ = prob of getting a sum $10$.

$p$ = $3/36$

and  $\bar p$ = prob of $NOT$ geeting a sum $10$.

$\bar p$ = $33/36$

$p+\bar p= 1$

now there are two possibilities:

(i) $1,~~~3,~~~5~~$ has an option of getting a sum or not but $2,4$ are constrained of not getting a sum 10.

$\color{red}{1} ~~~2 ~~~\color{red}{3}~~~4~~~\color{red}{5}~~~6~~~7~~~8$

probability = $(p+\bar p)*\bar p*(p+\bar p)*\bar p*(p+\bar p)*\bar p*p*p = p^2 \bar p^3$

(ii) $~~1~~~\color{red}{2}~~~3~~~\color{red}{4}~~~5~~~6~~~7~~~8$

probability= $\bar p*(p+\bar p)*\bar p*(p+\bar p)*\bar p*\bar p*p*p = p^2 \bar p^4$

therefore required probability = $p^2 \bar p^3 +p^2 \bar p^4 =  ~p^2 \bar p^3 (1+\bar p) $

PS: long but easy to understand :) .

Comment: You have overlooked the possibility that the second and third throws each have a sum of $10$, which satisfies the condition.

Comment: well, I've added the equation in (i) and (ii), which means either one getting a possibility at a time so second and third throw both doesn't occur a sum of 10 at a time. @N.F.Taussig